# Is there a better way to avoid function re-creation on render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

We know that it's a good idea to avoid arrow functions/bind/creating functions inside `render` because those functions will be re-created on every render.

Given the following possibly-memory-inefficient component:

```
const MyComponent = ({ ItemId, onSomeEvent }) => 
{
  return <SomeOtherComponent onSomeEvent={ val => onSomeEvent(itemId, val) } />;
};
```

I would probably re-write this as:

```
const MyComponent = React.createClass({
  someItemId: 0,
  onSomeEvent: () => {},
  someHandler(emittedValue){
    this.onSomeEvent(this.someItemId, emittedValue);
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    const { itemId, onSomeEvent } = this.props;
    this.someItemId = itemId;
    this.onSomeEvent = onSomeEvent;
  },
  render() {
    <SomeOtherComponent onSomeEvent={ this.someHandler } />
  };
});
```

The only reason I'm doing this is to avoid function re-creation in the render method. What is a better way of doing this? The way I'm doing it seems overly verbose. Thoughts?

Comment: Instantiating a Function instance is probably a much, much cheaper operation than almost any DOM manipulation. Do you have actual profiler evidence that your code is wasting time instantiating functions?

Comment: Absolutely no evidence at all. It may be an optimisation that simply isn't worth it. That's part of this really, wanting to see whether the trade off in best-practice is really worth it. It's not with my current solution.

Comment: Well Function (arrow or traditional) literals *seem* like they'd be expensive, but if you think about it, the runtime only has to worry about the actual *code* of the function once - because it's immutable, it can be shared by every instance. So a new Function object is probably pretty cheap, comparable to a new Array or something.

Comment: compiler do crazy stuff, so sometimes it can be the way that even optimisations that you think make things faster make it slower, don't care about such low level things, the time you waste on such optimisations you could use to write awesome programs.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to assign the function on `componentDidMount`. You can call props functions directly.

```
const MyComponent = React.createClass({
  propTypes: {
    itemId: React.PropTypes.number.isRequired
    onSomeEvent: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired
  },
  someHandler(emittedValue){
    this.props.onSomeEvent(this.props.itemId, emittedValue);
  }
  render() {
    <SomeOtherComponent onSomeEvent={ this.someHandler } />
  };
});
```

Also remember to use prop types, your future self will thank you :)